# Knapsack 1/0 Implementation needs explanation

Tags: c, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to understand this dynamic programming approach to the [Knapsack 1/0 Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) but i fail to get the algorithm.

Would somebody please be so kind as to explain this specific implementation, taken from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/0-1#C) to me?

Updating the code with some comments would help a lot!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
        const char * name;
        int weight, value;
} item_t;

item_t item[] = {
        {"map",                     9,       150},
        {"compass",                 13,      35},
        {"water",                   153,     200},
        {"sandwich",                50,      160},
        {"glucose",                 15,      60},
        {"tin",                     68,      45},
        {"banana",                  27,      60},
        {"apple",                   39,      40},
        {"cheese",                  23,      30},
        {"beer",                    52,      10},
        {"suntancream",             11,      70},
        {"camera",                  32,      30},
        {"T-shirt",                 24,      15},
        {"trousers",                48,      10},
        {"umbrella",                73,      40},
        {"waterproof trousers",     42,      70},
        {"waterproof overclothes",  43,      75},
        {"note-case",               22,      80},
        {"sunglasses",              7,       20},
        {"towel",                   18,      12},
        {"socks",                   4,       50},
        {"book",                    30,      10}
};

#define n_items (sizeof(item)/sizeof(item_t))

typedef struct {
        uint32_t bits; /* 32 bits, can solve up to 32 items */
        int value;
} solution;


void optimal(int weight, int idx, solution *s)
{
        solution v1, v2;
        if (idx < 0) {
                s->bits = s->value = 0;
                return;
        }

        if (weight < item[idx].weight) {
                optimal(weight, idx - 1, s);
                return;
         }

        optimal(weight, idx - 1, &v1);
        optimal(weight - item[idx].weight, idx - 1, &v2);

        v2.value += item[idx].value;
        v2.bits |= (1 << idx);

        *s = (v1.value >= v2.value) ? v1 : v2;
}

int main(void)
{
        int i = 0, w = 0;
        solution s = {0, 0};
        optimal(400, n_items - 1, &s);

        for (i = 0; i < n_items; i++) {
                if (s.bits & (1 << i)) {
                        printf("%s\n", item[i].name);
                        w += item[i].weight;
                }
        }
        printf("Total value: %d; weight: %d\n", s.value, w);
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance,
skylla

Comment: I dont understand exactly why solutions v1 and v2 are used, what they are used for, what the 2 if-conditions at the beginning of optimal() mean.... I just wanted to ask for an explanation of the sequence of events with a short explanation WHY things are done the way they are

Comment: For each item in the array, you only have two choices, add it to the current list, or not add it to the list. The solution basically generate all the possibilities and compare them. Look at the answer below, I think he explained every thing for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand exactly why solutions v1 and v2 are used, what they are used for

They correspond to the choices of not including or including, respectively, the item with index "idx" in the solution.

> what the 2 if-conditions at the beginning of optimal() mean....

`if (idx < 0)` means simply there are no more items to consider, it's the end of the recursion

`if (weight < item[idx].weight)` checks the if it's possible at all to include item `idx`. It's not possible to include if its own weight is greater than the limit weight.

Also, note that this is not a dynamic programming, but a simple recursive algorithm that generates all possible subsets of elements (the recursion tree pruned here and there).